# Scaling a rectangle up to match a bitmap

Tags: android, image, bitmap, android-bitmap

I'm trying to crop a bitmap. I first scale the original bitmap down to fit inside a view, then I draw a rectangle on the view that the user can move around and scale to crop the image, much like you can do in instagram when you import a picture from your gallery. The problem I'm having is scaling the rectangle up to match the original bitmap scale to crop from. Here is what's happening:

The middle of the square is what the final result should be

[image]

And what we actually get back:
[image]

I know it's just math but I spent hours last night trying to get it figured out.. What am I doing wrong?

```
Bitmap bmp;


float scalefactor = (float)this.mOriginalBitmap.getWidth() / (float)this.mBmpScaledForView.getWidth();


float dh = (this.mCropBoxRect.right - this.mCropBoxRect.left) * (scalefactor-1f);
float dv = (this.mCropBoxRect.bottom - this.mCropBoxRect.top) * (scalefactor-1f);

float l = (float)this.mCropBoxRect.left + dh/2f;
float r = (float)this.mCropBoxRect.right + dh/2f;

float t = (float)this.mCropBoxRect.top + dv/2f;
float b = (float)this.mCropBoxRect.bottom + dv/2f;

RectF scaleRec = new RectF(l, t, r, b);

bmp = Bitmap.createBitmap(this.mOriginalBitmap, (int)scaleRec.left, (int)scaleRec.top, (int)scaleRec.width(), (int)scaleRec.height());

bmp = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bmp, MyConsts.outputSize, MyConsts.outputSize, false);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to get it to work by using a matrix. The answer is pretty simple, it was just arriving there what was difficult for me.

```
Bitmap bmp;

//Get the scale factors for both vertical and horizontal since we're dealing with a square inside of a rectangle 
float scalefactorH = (float)mOriginalBitmap.getWidth() / (float)mBmpScaledForView.getWidth();
float scalefactorV = (float)mOriginalBitmap.getHeight() / (float)mBmpScaledForView.getHeight();

//Create a matrix and apply the scale factors
Matrix m = new Matrix();
m.postScale(scalefactorH, scalefactorV);

//Apply the matrix to a RectF
RectF crop = new RectF(mCropBoxRect);
m.mapRect(crop);

//And finally hit the bitmap with this diddy
bmp = Bitmap.createBitmap(this.mOriginalBitmap, (int)crop.left - mOffsetX, (int)crop.top - mOffsetY, (int)crop.width() - mOffsetX, (int)crop.height() - mOffsetY);
```

Comment: Please define what is mBmpScaledForView in this. As I get mOriginalBitmap is original bitmap while mOffsetX and mOffsetY is some kind of fix value.

Comment: Please how do you calculate mOffsetX and mOffsetY ?